# archive.ubuntu.com missing raring-updates

Tags: linux-mint, apt, repository

My Linux Mint 15 install on VirtualBox was working great up until about two days ago, when the updater started throwing a ton of errors and refuses to progress with any `apt-get update`, `apt-get install`, or `apt-get upgrade`.

They are 404 errors on the `archive.ubuntu.com` site, under the `/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates` folder. I looked at it, it doesn't exist. [Here's](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/) a direct link, which shows there is no raring-updates.

Where has `raring-updates` gone and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Support for Ubuntu 13.04 officially ended on January 27, 2014.

[Wikpedia entry on Raring Ringtail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_13.04_.28Raring_Ringtail.29). Presumably, you would want to update to a supported version... The current version of Linux Mint is [17](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php).

Comment: I wonder when I missed these releases.

Answer (score 16):

On AskUbuntu there is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) which may of help

The repositories for [EOL Ubuntu releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_life) are archived, so http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ was moved to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ (raring-updates is [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/)) - basically all you should need to do is replace `archive.ubuntu.com` & `security.ubuntu.com` in the software sources (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, then run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to missing hardware support, I cannot update to a newer version of Ubuntu than 13.04, so I have to rely on archived stuff like this. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Bart - you could use a version of Ubuntu like 12.04 LTS, as that will still be supported for a while (2017 or something)... 13.04 should still work though as long as you change the repositories source.

Comment: I know, but thanks for the suggestion anyway. I'm actually using Linux Mint 15 (Olivia) which is based on Ubuntu 13.04. While previous versions work (Mint 13 (Maya) is based on 12.04LTS), it's really a bit outdated in many ways, and I'm happy I can at least use something "near recent". I can live with the fact that most apps will never be updated anymore, if only I can install them. With this "old-releases" repo I can :)

Comment: old-releases does not have raring under ports.

Answer (score 4):

Try this version of */etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list* :

```
deb http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/packages.linuxmint.com/packages/ olivia main upstream import 

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/  raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner
```

Comment: This worked for me, I also had to ensure my /etc/apt/sources.list was empty.